# Visual Studio > Team Explorer > Changes > Compare with unmodified. How to Copy Left/Right?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 Community on Windows. I have used previous versions of Visual Studio, though only 2013 and older. At my previous company we also used a different VCS, so I am relatively new to Git.

After cloning the company repo and branching, I have been hacking files to see what various parts of the software do. Now, I'd like to see what changes have been made, so went to `Team Explorer > Changes > (right-click file of interest) > Compare with Unmodified...`. The View Mode is set to "Side-by-side" and I am able to see additions and deletions to the file compared with the latest version in the Git repo. Great!

But I've been using the fantastic [WinMerge difference tool](https://winmerge.org/) which allows you to perform actions such as:

- Copy Right
- Copy Right and Advance
- ...and the "Copy Left x" alternative

If there is something similar in Visual Studio, the options would be subtly different. For example, `Copy Right` would be something like `Revert to Unmodified`. And `Copy Left` might be something like `Keep Local Change`.

Does Visual Studio > Team Explorer have this type of feature?

Answer (score 0):

When you are running "Compare with unmodified ...", the editor shows you a view of your file (which is editable by you) with what git has in store (which you will not edit, not as a regular file at least).

In this context, the actions you describe make sense : you can edit your version, and none of the actions presented by the editor imply that "the version in git" will be edited that way.

---

Try asking Visual Studio to diff two files on your disk, and see what the actions look like in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I too miss this function. It seems to only be available when you have a merge conflict between two branches. Then you have the option to take the line that you prefer, and VS gives you a preview of the changes (which I don't think WinMerge does).

I guess you could create a branch for your changes and then merge the two branches.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-resolve-conflicts?view=vs-2022

Comment: Please include a snippet, links can change in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JonatanKruszewski, do you mean a snippet of a picture from the link I provided? The intent of the link was to provide an impression of how the merge looks like in VS. I'm not comfortable saving images and uploading them here again.